# Can you explain to my daughter's second grade teacher why this is a complete sentence?

Tags: sentence

"Pound on that door to open it." Can you explain why this is a complete sentence?

Comment: The "You" is implied.  Perfectly valid English.  As to "complete", I suppose one could claim that even though it's valid it's not "complete" since it doesn't have an explicit subject, but that's a pretty weak argument.

Comment: See, this right here is why educators should be paid more. So that people with an IQ above room temperature consider applying to these jobs, and questions like this never need to be asked...

Comment: Or would we just be paying people with an IQ **lower* than room temperature that much more than they are worth?

Answer (score 6):

"Pound on" is used in the imperative, with an implied subject (you), and an object (door), with "that" being a demonstrative adjective or determiner. So "(You) pound on that door" has a subject, a verb and an object, and is a complete sentence.

Comment: Sounds like a "great" school.